# Why PostgreSQL doesn't use an index for JOIN

Tags: postgresql, indexing, query-optimization

I have two tables "Tasks"(300k rows) and "TaskAssignedRoles"(500k rows).

```
CREATE TABLE public."Tasks" (
"ID" uuid NOT NULL,
"RowID" uuid NOT NULL,
"Planned" timestamptz NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT "pk_Tasks" PRIMARY KEY ("RowID")
);
CREATE INDEX "idx_Tasks_ID" ON public."Tasks" USING btree ("ID");

CREATE TABLE public."TaskAssignedRoles" (
"ID" uuid NOT NULL,
"RowID" uuid NOT NULL,
"TaskRoleID" uuid NOT NULL,
"RoleID" uuid NOT NULL,
"RoleName" text NOT NULL,
"RoleTypeID" uuid NOT NULL,
"ParentRowID" uuid NULL,
CONSTRAINT "pk_TaskAssignedRoles" PRIMARY KEY ("RowID")
);
CREATE INDEX "idx_TaskAssignedRoles_ID" 
    ON public."TaskAssignedRoles" USING btree ("ID");
CREATE INDEX "ndx_TaskAssignedRoles_TaskRoleID" 
    ON public."TaskAssignedRoles" USING btree ("TaskRoleID") 
        INCLUDE ("ID", "RoleID", "RoleName", "RoleTypeID")
        WHERE (("ParentRowID" IS NULL) AND ("TaskRoleID" = 'f726ab6c-a279-4d79-863a-47253e55ccc1'::uuid));
```

I'm running the query:

```
explain (analyze)
SELECT t.*, tarp."RoleID", tarp."RoleName"
FROM "Tasks" AS "t"
INNER JOIN "TaskAssignedRoles" AS tarp 
    ON "tarp"."ID" = "t"."RowID" 
        AND "tarp"."TaskRoleID" = 'f726ab6c-a279-4d79-863a-47253e55ccc1' 
        AND "tarp"."ParentRowID" IS NULL
```

I get the plan:

```
Merge Join (cost=73.06..41145.44 rows=229928 width=434) (actual time=0.024..945.202 rows=234668 loops=1)
   Merge Cond: (t."RowID" = tarp."ID")
   -> Index Scan using "pk_Tasks" on "Tasks" t (cost=0.42..13861.52 rows=234668 width=388) (actual time=0.007..227.215 rows=234668 loops=1)
   -> Index Scan using "idx_TaskAssignedRoles_ID" on "TaskAssignedRoles" tarp (cost=0.42..23823.15 rows=229928 width=62) (actual time=0.013..541.680 rows=234668 loops=1)
         Filter: (("ParentRowID" IS NULL) AND ("TaskRoleID" = 'f726ab6c-a279-4d79-863a-47253e55ccc1'::uuid))
         Rows Removed by Filter: 280198
Planning Time: 0.353 ms
Execution Time: 953.534 ms
```

Tell me why Postgres does not use the ndx_TaskAssignedRoles_TaskRoleID index, although it fully matches the condition in the query?

Comment: I think, index ``idx_TaskAssignedRoles_ID`` is used for best cost for JOIN. In plan  ``cost of Join``=3x``cost of SCAN``. If ``ndx_TaskAssignedRoles_TaskRoleID`` is used, JOIN cost increases significantly, my be needed, sort on ``tarp.Id`` or hash join on uuid(.

Comment: Сan try btree("ID","TaskRoleID","ParentRowID") INCLUDE ("RoleName")

Comment: Yes, you were right. Index btree("ID","TaskRoleID","ParentRowID") INCLUDE ("RoleName") worked. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is that while you think the index covers the query, it actually does not.  Here are the columns from the `TaskAssignedRoles` table involved in the join condition:

```
ID
TaskRoleID
ParentRowID
```

Your index only includes the `TaskRoleID` column.  The thing to realize here is that the `INCLUDE` clause only includes those column values at the leaf nodes of the B-tree; the columns are not otherwise structurally part of the index.  Similarly, the `WHERE` clause just restricts the records in the table to some subset before creating the index.  But again, the columns in the `WHERE` clause are not part of the index.

Try using this version:

```sql
CREATE INDEX "ndx_TaskAssignedRoles_TaskRoleID" 
ON public."TaskAssignedRoles" USING btree ("TaskRoleID", "RoleID", "ID")
    INCLUDE ("RoleName")
    WHERE "ParentRowID" IS NULL
```

This index would seem to completely cover the join condition.  The `INCLUDE` clause includes one column needed by the select.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I recreated the index according to your advice, but the query plan did not change.

Answer (score 0):

In my hands it is willing to use the index, against empty tables.

It probably doesn't do that for you because it thinks it will be slower.  To do a nested loop driven by your desired index, it thinks it would need to hit the other table and index 229,928 times.  That is not cheap.  It would rather do a bulk-friendly operation instead.